# 'DefaultConnection' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, connection-string, ef-database-first

I'm getting this error when logging into my application.

In the web config, the connection string looks like this...

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-tvc-20150209111912.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-tvc-20150209111912;Integrated Security=True" />
```

How can I resolve this error?

This connection string is only used for authentication. I have other connection strings that handle other site data, which are working properly.

Comment: try putting providerName attribute at the end

Comment: Thanks - but it started out there. I moved it trying to solve this error.

Comment: I think your connection string is incorrect. What type of database are you trying to connect to?

Comment: check out some SQL Server connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Its actually generated by Visual Studio, I never edited it.

Comment: If you remove the `providerName` attribute do you still get the same error or do you get something different (sounds stupid I know). Also, do you have a duplicate connection string in your config by any chance?

Comment: try changing the connection string, this one clearly not working for you

Comment: Brent - good idea, but same error. There are 3 connection strings, but no dupe default. I should mention the error only occurs on the remote server, not on local.

Comment: Double check your AppPool user context has read/write permissions to the `.mdf` file in your app, i.e. NetworkService or IIS_USR etc. Second to that make sure you aren't missing any assemblies in your deployment, i.e. `System.Data.dll`

Comment: What happens if you remove the entry for DefaultConnection altogether?

Answer (score 3):

Try putting providerName attribute at the end

Comment: Would you mind removing this answer so others will be more likely to look at the question?